# How to disconnect user from radius?

Tags: linux, centos6

I want to disconnect user from radius but it is not working. i am using this command

```
echo User-Name=$loginId,Framed-IP-Address=$framedipaddress | /usr/local/bin/radclient -x $nasIp:$nasPort disconnect $naspass"
```

it showing a error like:

radclient: no response from server for ID 91 socket 3.I am using linux centos.

Answer (score 0):

echo Command string should be in double quotes. You may not need the framed IP address rather you'd need the client's mac address and User-Name. The password specified should the Radius password that has been set in the clients.conf file.

```
echo "User-Name=radusertester,Calling-Station-ID=80-CE-B9-70-42-BD" | /usr/local/bin/radclient 127.0.0.1:3799 disconnect radpass
```